# Huge Difference in result when calculating distance b/w two points using longitude-latitude

Tags: python, django, postgis, geodjango, haversine

I am attempting to calculate the distance between two Positions using SRID(32148)
Here are my two points

```
Point-1:
Lat:46.489767 Long:-119.043221
Point-2:
Lat:47.610902 Long:-122.336422
```

[This](https://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/) website states that the distance in miles b/w these two points is 173.388 however from the code below the result I am getting is 0.002161632093865483

This is the code that I am using

```
    employeeloc = modelEmployee.objects.filter(user__first_name="adam")[0].location
    employerloc = modelEmployer.objects.filter(user__first_name="adam")[0].location
    meters = employerloc.distance(employeeloc)
    #Caluclate in miles
    dobj = Distance(m=meters)
    mi = dobj.mi
```

This is a little more detail with debugging results attached
[image]
Any suggestions on why my result is so different ?

**Update:**

I tried transforming the position using the following code using SRID 4326. However the results are still incorrect

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have used the lon / lat coordinates as SRID(32148) ones; you need to transform them.

This **incorrect** query gives your result 3.47m, because the coordinates don't match the SRID:

```
select 
st_distance(
st_setsrid(st_point(-122.336422,47.610902),32148),
st_setsrid(st_point(-119.043221,46.489767),32148))
-- 3.47880964046985
```

This query gives you the 173.71 mi result you expect:

```
select 
st_distance(
st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(-122.336422,47.610902),4326),32148),
st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(-119.043221,46.489767),4326),32148))

--279558.106935732m (=173.71mi)
```

And that is similar to the result of this query:

```
select 
st_distance(
st_setsrid(st_point(-122.336422,47.610902),4326)::geography,
st_setsrid(st_point(-119.043221,46.489767),4326)::geography)

--279522.55326056 m (= 173.69 mi)
```

Comment: what is 4326 ? Can you explain that please ?

Comment: 4326 is the SRID of the WGS84 reference system of lon/lat - i.e. it's the SRID of your coordinates.

Comment: I tried using your suggestion of transformation and I got a different result. I am updating my post

Comment: just updated my post - I am transforming my location however I still get an incorrect result

Comment: Looks like you haven't solved the underlying problem, which is that your SOURCE (the coords) are in 4326 but you have set it to 32148. You need to set the location SRID to 4326, then transform it to 32148 - your update is the wrong way round I think.